# MySQL - Count number of times ITEMS were sold - Admin Stat Page

Tags: mysql

I have a following **solditems** table

```
+---------+--------+----------+
| orderid | itemid | unitsold |
+---------+--------+----------+
| 1       | ITEM1  | 2        |
+---------+--------+----------+
| 2       | ITEM2  | 5        |
+---------+--------+----------+
| 3       | ITEM1  | 1        |
+---------+--------+----------+
| 4       | ITEM3  | 1        |
+---------+--------+----------+
```

I need to find the following values to show on my stats page.

1. Total unit sold
2. Total number of items sold only once
3. Total number of items sold more than once

Query for the 1st question

```
SELECT sum(unitsold) AS total FROM solditems;
```

For the 2nd question I am using the following query

```
SELECT 
    itemid, SUM(unitsold) AS total
FROM
    solditems
GROUP BY itemid
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

And getting the following result

```
+--------+-------+
| itemid | total |
+--------+-------+
| ITEM2  | 5     |
+--------+-------+
| ITEM1  | 3     |
+--------+-------+
| ITEM3  | 1     |
+--------+-------+
```

For question 2, how do I get the answer **1** as there is only **one** item **ITEM3** sold only **once**.

And for question 3, how do I get the answer **2** as there are **two** items **ITEM1** and **ITEM2** which were sold **more than once**.

I am able to list the items that were sold once and more than once by using "HAVING" in the query.

```
SELECT 
    itemid, SUM(unitsold) AS total
FROM
    solditems
GROUP BY itemid
HAVING total = 1
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

to get items that were sold only once.

```
+--------+-------+
| itemid | total |
+--------+-------+
| ITEM3  | 1     |
+--------+-------+
```

And

```
SELECT 
    itemid, SUM(unitsold) AS total
FROM
    solditems
GROUP BY itemid
HAVING total > 1
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

to get items that were sold more than once.

```
+--------+-------+
| itemid | total |
+--------+-------+
| ITEM2  | 5     |
+--------+-------+
| ITEM1  | 3     |
+--------+-------+
```

How should I modify my query to get the following answers.

Question 2: Answer total = 1 [i.e., total number of items sold only once]

Question 3: Answer total = 2 [i.e., total number of items sold more than once]

**ANSWER**

For Question 2:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT itemid) AS total
FROM
    solditems
WHERE
    itemid IN (SELECT 
            itemid
        FROM
            solditems
        GROUP BY itemid
        HAVING SUM(unitsold) = 1);
```

For Question 3:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT itemid) AS total
FROM
    solditems
WHERE
    itemid IN (SELECT 
            itemid
        FROM
            solditems
        GROUP BY itemid
        HAVING SUM(unitsold) > 1);
```

I am getting the answer but want to check if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> **you can count from a select in MySQL**

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS amount_sold_once
FROM
    (SELECT 
        itemid, SUM(unitsold) AS total
    FROM
        solditems
    GROUP BY itemid
    HAVING total = 1
    ORDER BY total DESC) AS sold_once
```

Just watch out that the select statement you want to count from
is in round brackets () and has its own alias.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `HAVING` section at your query.

```
    SELECT 
        itemid, SUM(unitsold) AS total
    FROM
        solditems
    GROUP BY itemid HAVING SUM(unitsold) > 1
    ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: i have tried both the queries earlier and i am able to list the items sold once and more than once. but how do i get the number of items sold once and more than once? i have updated the question please check if you can figure out the required query for this problem.

Comment: For your third question answer should be
   
  SELECT 
        COUNT(itemid)
    FROM
        solditems
    GROUP BY itemid HAVING SUM(unitsold) > 1

Answer (score 0):

For your question 2.Try this query.

```
SELECT 
    itemid, count(itemid) AS total
FROM
    solditems
GROUP BY itemid HAVING  total= 1
```

And for question 3 try this

```
SELECT 
    itemid, count(itemid) AS total
FROM
    solditems
GROUP BY itemid HAVING  total>1
```

Comment: i have tried both the queries earlier and i am able to list the items sold once and more than once. but how do i get the number of items sold once and more than once? i have updated the question please check if you can figure out the required query for this problem.

Comment: i found the answer plz check if there is a better way to write the query i used to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this query

```
select itemid ,sum(unitsold) as unitsold from solditems 
where itemid in(select distinct(itemid )
 from solditems) orderby unitsold asc;
```